# PRISM: How to add a view model to a region and create the view automatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I´m new to PRISM and trying some things out. I´m struggeling a little bit with MVVM.

The way you "connect" a view with a viewmodel is clear:

- injection through unity, or
- set the data context manually (ServiceLocator)

Everything is working fine if I add a view to a region (the viewmodel is created automatically). But that´s not the use case.

Let´s take a look at the example:

```
public class MyViewModel : NotificationObject
{
   public ObservableCollection<AnotherViewModel> OrderModel { get; private set; }
}
```

I have to create view models and add them to the collection. This view models have to be displayed (AnotherView) in a region (OrderRegion). My problem is, how can I achieve that now the view is created when I am adding a viewmodel to a region. This region is a TabControl, so it could happened that different views must be displayed.

I have already took a look to the PRISM Quickstarts and the StockTrader example. What I am looking for is quite similar to

```
 virtual protected void StartOrder(string tickerSymbol, TransactionType transactionType)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tickerSymbol))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Resources.StringCannotBeNullOrEmpty, "tickerSymbol"));
        }
        this.ShowOrdersView();

        IRegion ordersRegion = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.OrdersRegion];

        var orderCompositeViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IOrderCompositeViewModel>();

        orderCompositeViewModel.TransactionInfo = new TransactionInfo(tickerSymbol, transactionType);
        orderCompositeViewModel.CloseViewRequested += delegate
        {
            OrderModels.Remove(orderCompositeViewModel);
            commandProxy.SubmitAllOrdersCommand.UnregisterCommand(orderCompositeViewModel.SubmitCommand);
            commandProxy.CancelAllOrdersCommand.UnregisterCommand(orderCompositeViewModel.CancelCommand);
            commandProxy.SubmitOrderCommand.UnregisterCommand(orderCompositeViewModel.SubmitCommand);
            commandProxy.CancelOrderCommand.UnregisterCommand(orderCompositeViewModel.CancelCommand);
            ordersRegion.Remove(orderCompositeViewModel);
            if (ordersRegion.Views.Count() == 0)
            {
                this.RemoveOrdersView();
            }
        };

        ordersRegion.Add(orderCompositeViewModel);
        OrderModels.Add(orderCompositeViewModel);

        commandProxy.SubmitAllOrdersCommand.RegisterCommand(orderCompositeViewModel.SubmitCommand);
        commandProxy.CancelAllOrdersCommand.RegisterCommand(orderCompositeViewModel.CancelCommand);
        commandProxy.SubmitOrderCommand.RegisterCommand(orderCompositeViewModel.SubmitCommand);
        commandProxy.CancelOrderCommand.RegisterCommand(orderCompositeViewModel.CancelCommand);

        ordersRegion.Activate(orderCompositeViewModel);
    }
```

The view model is created inside the code and added to the region. The whole type regestring is happend through the "ViewExportAttribute" so it makes it harder to understand the pattern behind it.

EDIT:

I have found a way to do this manually but it´s not very nice:

```
var view = (FrameworkElement) ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AnotherView>();
var model = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AnotherViewModel>();
view.DataContext = model;

regionManager.Regions["OrderRegion"].Add(view, null, true);
regionManager.Regions["OrderRegion"].Activate(view);
```

Roman

EDIT2:

Hi, I´m sorry, maybe I wasn´t clear enough.

My goal was to create a view model and then to configure it like in the example from the StockTrader above: Subscribe events, commands etc.  After that I want to add this view model to the region, so that´s it could be displayed. This region might be a tabcontrol where different views with different view models are displayed.
The order is:

1. Create a view model in the controller class
2. Configure the view model
3. Add the view model to local collection inside the controller
4. Add the view model to the region

The missing piece what I was looking for was how to make it happen, that the view is created “automatically” with all stuff like binding etc. I have found an approach in this article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/229931/Understand-MVVM-Using-PRISM-by-Hello-World-Silverl). I have to create own interfaces for the view and the view model (IAnotherViewModel, IAnotherView).

Another approach can be found here: http://paulstovell.com/blog/viewmodel-first-prism

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having difficulty understanding what your question is?  From your edit it appears you're trying to manually create views into a region.  You do not appear to be leveraging the power of WPF binding nor an IoC container.  However, without more detail I'm afraid I cannot assist here.

Comment: Hi Backlash, I have edited the question. By the way, what do you mean exactly with “You do not appear to be leveraging the power of WPF binding nor an IoC container.” I´m using the IUnityContainer inside the Module.Initialize() Method to register the types (container.RegisterType<IAnotherViewModel>, AnotherViewModel >())

Comment: Ok, I think I see the basic difference here.  You're creating a "ViewModel first" approach.  I.e. create a view model object, create a view object, then combine the two via the DataContext.  My personal approach is to inject the viewmodels into the view, so when using an IoC container, the view model construction/configuration is handled automatically.  There are a bunch of techniques to use in a view model first approach.  Rachel's technique below is quite popular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any reason not to use implicit `DataTemplates` for this?

They are `DataTemplates` that define a `DataType` property, but not a `Key` property, and they are used anytime WPF tries to draw an object of the specified DataType

For example,

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModelCollection}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewModel}">
    <!-- This could also go elsewhere, like Application.Resources -->
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelA}">
            <local:ViewA />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelB}">
            <local:ViewB />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

If the `TabControl` is displaying an object of type `ViewModelA`, it will draw it using `ViewA`, and if it's displaying `ViewModelB`, it will draw it using `ViewB`

Answer (score 0):

yI you are using  MEF then you can automate your view registration using Attributes:

```
/*YOUR VIEW*/
    [ExportViewToRegion("MyView", "MyRegion")]
        [Export(typeof(MyView))]
        public partial class MyView : UserControl
        { 
         ....
        }


/*IMPLEMENTATION*/

   public interface IExportViewToRegionMetadata
    {
         string ViewName { get; }
         string TargetRegion { get; }
    }

    [MetadataAttribute]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class ExportViewToRegionAttribute : ExportAttribute
    {
        public ExportViewToRegionAttribute(string viewName, string targetRegion)
            : base(typeof(UserControl))
        {
            ViewName = viewName;
            TargetRegion = targetRegion;
        }


        public string ViewName { get; private set; }
        public string TargetRegion { get; private set; }
    }


    [Export(typeof(IFluentRegionManager))]
    public class FluentRegionManager : IFluentRegionManager, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
    {
        public IRegionManager RegionManager { get; set; }

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public FluentRegionManager(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            RegionManager = regionManager;
        }


        /*This Import will find all views in the assembly with attribute [ExportViewToRegion("ViewName", "RegionName")]*/
        [ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true)]
        public Lazy<UserControl, IExportViewToRegionMetadata>[] Views { get; set; }



        private readonly List<string> _processedViews = new List<string>();

        private Lazy<UserControl, IExportViewToRegionMetadata> _GetViewInfo(string viewName)
        {
            return (from v in Views where v.Metadata.ViewTypeForRegion.Equals(viewName) select v).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public IExportViewToRegionMetadata this[string viewName]
        {
            get
            {
                return (from v in Views
                        where v.Metadata.ViewName.Equals(viewName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                        select v.Metadata).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

        public void ExportViewToRegion(string viewName)
        {

            if (viewName==null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("viewName");
            }

            var viewInfo = _GetViewInfo(viewName);

            string targetRegion;
            UserControl _view;

            if (viewInfo != null)
            {
                targetRegion = viewInfo.Metadata.TargetRegion;
                _view = viewInfo.Value;
            }


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetRegion) || _processedViews.Contains(viewName)) return;

            RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(targetRegion,  _view.GetType());
            _processedViews.Add(viewName);
        }


        /*All required views has been discovered and imported */
        /*Loop true collection and register view with the region */
        public void OnImportsSatisfied()
        {
            foreach (var viewName in  from view in Views where !_processedViews.Contains(view.Metadata.ViewName) 
                select view.Metadata.ViewName)
            {
                ExportViewToRegion(viewName);
            }
        }
    }

/* finally call IFluentRegionManager import in the bootstrapper to kick off registration*/
```